# Manipulating JSON data, when keys may be missing, in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I need to add a few values to many JSON objects. Here is an outline of the values I need to add.

```
{'foo':
   {'bar':
      {'alpha':
         [
           {'bravo':'charlie'},{'delta':'echo'}
         ]
      }
   }
 }
```

In some instances the `foo` key is missing from the object to be edited; other times everything is there and I just need to add `bravo` and `delta`. It is also possible that everything required is there and nothing needs to be changed. Sometimes key `alpha` contains a dictionary any not a list of dictionaries.

What options do I have for modifying the JSON object keeping all the original data in tact? Is there a good alternative to writing a handful of conditionals to check how many of the keys currently exist then adding in the rest?

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is the question. Can you be more specific? Perhaps you can show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I currently have a handful of if statements checking to see if a key exists. If the key does, I run another if statement to see if the next one exists and this will go on until I check to see if a specific value is set. Whenever a check fails it means I need to add in the rest of the tree starting at the point of failure. I would prefer to get rid of the many if statements.

Comment: Instead of describing your current code, please simply include a minimal sample of it in your question (there's an edit link right under it). That will make it a lot more obvious what you're current approach is, and allows others to more easily suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you convert JSON to Python dictionary.

```
 import json

 data = json.loads(myjsonstring)
```

Then Python dictionaries have few helpful methods you should know about.

```
 data.get("alpha", 0)   # instead of data["alpha"], return default value 0 if alpha is missing
```

If you need to set some value in the dictionary if it is not yet there:

```
bravo_value = data.setdefault("bravo", [])  # Initializes bravo with an empty list if it is missing
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm

At the end of your manipulation convert dictionary back to JSON:

```
myjsonstring = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: looks like I will stick to `data['nested']['key'].get('value',0)`

Comment: You can do data.get("nested", {}).get("key", {}).get("value", 0)

Comment: Also if you want to create the missing structure on the way data.setdefault("nested", {}).setdefault("key", 0), get("value", 0)

Answer (score 1):

The ability to create a ragged data structure without having to check for existence of each level of the structure or to check for values which may be nested within the datastructure without throwing exceptions everytime you try to access a levelt hat doesn't exist is called auto-vivification.  You get this behavior out of the box with perl.  With python you have to work a bit more for it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification